# Web based version control for documents

Tags: version-control, documents

I'm looking for a Version Control system that has a pretty front end that I can customize to look the way I want.

Users need to have the ability to upload documents and edit them - Based on their access level. Some documents will require a higher access level to edit. Some documents will be available for download to all users and some will be more privatized that require higher access levels.

The documents will need to have a Date Modified and a 'Currently Checkout' type thing - Which I guess is pretty standard with Version Control systems.

Having the ability to edit the documents in the site rather than having to download, edit and then reupload would be a huge bonus. Printing the documents in PDF would also be nice.

Does such a system exist?

EDIT: A web-based CMS can't be used as the Documents need to remain intact. DOCX files need to be DOCX files. Not web-based articles.

Answer (score 4):

SharePoint document libraries work exactly like this. It's free if you have a Windows Server 2003 or 2008 license.

Comment: Free in _price_, perhaps. But not in cost, sanity, morale, etc. :)

Comment: I strongly disagree. BTW, have you looked at SharePoint 2010?

Comment: I'm looking at it now. The price kind of turns me off it :/

Comment: @Logi: the price of _what_? It's free.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [Alfresco](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfresco_(software))

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing sounds less like a "web-based version control for documents", and more like a CMS with different access levels that also supports print to PDF and online editing. Have you considered, say, [**Drupal**](http://drupal.org/)?

Comment: They documents need to be just that. Documents. DOCX, XLS, etc... I can't have web-based articles

Comment: If the binary content of the document has to be preserved then, yes, I agree; Drupal isn't the right choice. The original question didn't make this distinction, though, so perhaps it's worth noting.